# Naming a class with for loop iteration #row-#{i} doesn't work

Tags: pug

I am trying to run a for loop that will create a divs with enumerated classes, why is this not working?

```
rows = 3
cols = 6

- for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    #row-#{i}
- }
```

I am getting back

```
<div id="row-"></div><0></0><div id="row-"></div><1></1><div id="row-"></div><2></2>
```

Comment: BTW, I found this extremely useful when answering your question: http://naltatis.github.com/jade-syntax-docs/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Template:

```
rows = 3
cols = 6

- for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    div(id='row-'+i)
- }
```

Outputs:

```
<div id="row-0"></div>
<div id="row-1"></div>
<div id="row-2"></div>
```

Though you said "enumerated *classes*" so perhaps you actually want:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    div(class='row-'+i)
- }
```